# if and else statement not working on the iframe php page

Tags: pages, templates

i want to use if and else statement on iframe but it's not working 
if and else statement not working on the iframe php page

```
<?php 

if("p=947"){
?>
 <iframe width="820px" height="1200px" style="overflow:hidden;margin-left:-900px; margin-top:-100px" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" src="<?php bloginfo ("template_url")?>/gallery/karachigallery.php" ></iframe>

<?php } else if("p=953") {?>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to test with the if statement?

Comment: Navigate through this [Stack archives](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions), you'll see lots of examples of working code.

Comment: This appears to be a **PHP syntax** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: @ChipBennett i'm using wordpress

Comment: *"I'm using WordPress"* - [Please refer to the FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): *Note that we **do not handle** questions... **not specific to WordPress** (even if they happen in its context)...* If your question is specific to WordPress, you need to edit it to indicate *how* it is specific to WordPress. As-written, it's simply a question of a PHP conditional clause.

Answer (score 1):

To test for a post id use `get_the_ID()`:

```
if ( 947 == get_the_ID() )
{
    // do something
}
```

If you need it outside of a loop you can access the post object’s `ID` member:

```
if ( 947 == $post->ID )
{
    // do something
}
```